# Polymer: How can I customize color and font size of paper header

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, polymer-starter-kit

How I can change the color and font-size of the header of a **paper-card** element using `--paper-card-header-color`?

I am looking at [this link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-card/pull/10/files) but not very sure how I can put the above attribute, i.e. `--paper-card-header-color` and the color value.

I tried like:

```html
<paper-card heading="Total Linear Sales" paper-card-header-color="#ff0000">
  <div class="card-content">
    ...
    ...
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Bit the above does not change the color.

I am not very familiar with Polymer yet, still learning basics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at are [Polymer's Custom CSS Properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details). You apply them like regular CSS properties:

```
paper-card {
    --paper-card-header-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Or inline:

```
<paper-card style="--paper-card-header-color: #ff0000">
```

Comment: Just for the completion of the question, this needs to be added too        --paper-card-header-text: {
            font-size: 80px;
        };

Comment: To deceze and Justin XL: Only additional thing I had to use was <style is="custom-style"> in order to make this to work! Thanks guys :)